# NSString to NSDate return null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here i am getting current time and check whether its in am/pm format. If its not like that, i convert 24 hour time format into 12 hour time format and add AM/PM manually.

This is my code:

```
- (NSString *) getCurrentTime {

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *currentTime = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:today];

currentTime = [self checkTimeFormat:currentTime];

return currentTime; 

}
```

And

```
  - (NSString *) checkTimeFormat:(NSString *) currentTime
{

NSArray *timeArray = [currentTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
int intHour = [[timeArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
NSString *lastVal = [timeArray objectAtIndex:2];

if ([lastVal rangeOfString:@"M"].location == NSNotFound) {

    if (intHour < 12)
        lastVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ AM", [timeArray objectAtIndex:2]];
    else
        lastVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ PM", [timeArray objectAtIndex:2]];
}

if (intHour > 12) 
    intHour = intHour - 12;        

currentTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%@:%@", intHour, [timeArray objectAtIndex:1], lastVal];
NSLog(@"Current Time ==>> %@", currentTime);

return currentTime;

}
```

Conversion of NSString into NSDate code below:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *testDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:getCurrentTime];
NSLog(@"testDate => %@", testDate);
```

If the Time is in 12 hour format (am/pm), testDate value is getting correctly.

If the Time is in 24 hour format, testDate value is **null**

What is the issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What should method `getCurrentTime` return? Do you want it to return a time in a 12-hour format regardless of user's locale?

Comment: I need to get current time in NSDate Time Format such like (1999-12-31 18:54:30 +0000). After that i will calculate timeIntervalSinceDate between two NSDate. Here getCurrentTime returns formatted current time  in NSString (Ex: 11:09:14 PM).

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. What `checkTimeFormat` should do?

Comment: I just need to display count down timer. Kindly suggest me.

Comment: First off, we need some examples of the time strings you're converting.  Second, if you find that you have a 24-hour format string you should simply set the date formatter to that rather than try to convert the 24 to 12.  Third, if you use a 12-hour format you should always set the locale to a "safe" one such as en_US_POSIX.

Comment: Fourth, your question/code makes absolutely no sense.  What is it you want to do?????

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *currentTime24 = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a];
NSDate *currentTime12 = [timeFormatter dateWithString:currentTime24];
NSString *currentTime = [timeFormatter stringWithDate:currentTime12];
```

Comment: Please give your solution for my question. NSString to NSDate return null value..

Comment: Sorry, I thougth you wanted a countdown timer. I've edit my response.